# How to get Double tap event using MvxListView in MVVMCROSS android mvvmview model

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, tap, mvxlistview

We are using below for listview we need to catch Double tap event of list in MVVM viewmodel

```
<MvxListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource ProductObsList;ItemClick ProductSelectedCommand;SelectedItem MyChosenItem;"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/_product"/>
```

please help us with proper solution

Answer (score 0):

ListView doesn't have anything built in for listening to Double Taps and that gesture is not very common in general.

If you absolutely need it, then you would probably want to implement it on your items adding a GestureDetector listening for double taps.

Also, you should really consider switching to RecyclerView instead for better performance.

Comment: Hi Cheesebaron
Do have any example of RecyclerView with Double tab.

<MvvmCross.DroidX.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/mvx_list_basket"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"           
         local:MvxBind="ItemsSource BasketObsList;ItemClick ItemSelectedCommand"
                local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/_basket"/>